# Что такое remoteKeyValueStorage

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, api

Читаю задачу учебную и написано сделать remoteKeyValueStorage на базе web api. С последним понятно информации много, а что такое remoteKeyValueStorage.

Comment: это удаленное хранилище пар ключ-значение

Comment: @tym32167 это дикшенари или что  то другое, и уделенное в смысле на сервере оно?

Comment: ну я не знаю, что конкретно имел ввиду препод, но по идее да, [что то типа словаря на сервере](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database)

Comment: @tym32167 получается, что если я сделаю веб апи и в нем сделаю это хранилище то это будет приемлемо, и запросами достаю от туда значения по ключу.

Comment: ну, сервер должен как минимум уметь CRUD, а вот будет ли этого достаточно - вопрос к вашему преподу